# android bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

Can someone explain to me the concept behind using bluetooth?

My project in my studies is to make an android app using bluetooth, SQLLIGHT and google app 
the app itself is a very easy one but I just dont get the tools I need to use :

How does the bluetooth works? Is there a simple example?
the concept behind android GUI (I already made one but I think I am not fully understood his power)?

note : I am using v 2.1

Answer (score 0):

For learning bluetooth on android I guess you should dig into: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html

Should be simple.

Answer (score 0):

Before you learn to program Bluetooth with API on a given platform, you need to read up a few basics first to understand the technology first. There are plenty of resource materials on internet for learning. If you prefer a book, you can try [http://www.amazon.com/Bluetooth-Operation-Use-Robert-Morrow/dp/007138779X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/007138779X)